# Change the volume serial number on a VM hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, hyper-v

Can I change the C-disk volume serial number on a virtual machine in Hyper-V? How can I do that?

The OS of the VM is Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: Th OS of the VM is critical to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any Windows system, you can change it using volume ID by Sysinternals (bought out by Microsoft):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897436.aspx

You will need to reboot.

Comment: That utility from Sysinternals is changing Volume ID, but in this case is needed to change HDD Serial Number.
So the question is still the same: How to change HDD Serial Number on Hyper-V virtual machine?

Comment: @Mark: No it was the volume ID I was asking for. It is sometimes called Volume Serial Number (example:  `dir C:` in dos prompt). I guess you are thinking of the physical serial number of the hard disk, but this is not what I need.